# UIKit 3 (getuikit) collapsible sidebar for admin dashboard interface design logic

Tags: html, css, user-interface, uikit, getuikit

What's the best combination of components to create (zero-dependency and totally UIKit-native) collapsible sidebar for admin dashboard (as in responsive and hide/show menu) seen on many admin templates? I'm looking at grid + accordian + animation + sticky + cards, but I'm not sure how to change the uk-width [1-3][3-4] responsively on resize or adaptively to user's viewport (not the show/hide utility uk-hidden or uk-visible thing). Please recommend, greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I was looking on the documentation and figured this can be achieve by using the [toggle component](https://getuikit.com/docs/toggle). I can effectively hide and show the sidebar on hover or hide it permanently using a button toggle instead of just totally hiding it from the user's smaller viewport using the uk-hidden/visible class. This means, the sidebar is still accessible from a toggle and it's useful for smaller screen. Thanks!